# Visual Studio Rebuild Solution hangs

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have a solution that is composed of six assemblies.  When I initially load the solution and try to build it, it seems that Visual studio just hangs. It says that it’s building, but I see no updates in the Output window.  The CPU jump to 100% usage. The only thing I can do is to Cancel the build or to shut down VS 2012 through Task Manager (which takes forever since I have little use of the system at the time due to the 100% cpu usage).

The only way I have been able to build my solution is to rebuild it.  Basically, I delete the .sln file. I then create a new one (by opening the first assembly) and build it. I open the next one…build it. I repeat this process until I have all assemblies built. Only after this am I able to rebuild the solution.

Note, that at some point, not sure when, I will once again not be able to build the solution and I have to go through this process over again.

Any ideas as to what might be causing this?

Here is some more information.

I am running VS 2010, VS 2012 and VS 2013 under a VMWare Virtual Machine. I do not think this matters as it open happens (as far as I can tell) with this one solution. It doesn't matter which version of VS I open it with, it will hang.

Really hoping someone can help me resolve this as it is eating into productivity.

UPDATE-----------------------
It appears that I am able to build this solution on the command line using MSBUILD. However, I still cannot debug the application since VS just hangs.

Comment: What about building outside visual studio? Command line with full logging. At least in 2012 a .sln file is something that msbuild understands.

Comment: John Saunders, I will try that. this is very frustrating. I got it to build, but now I can't debug, it hang. So even if I can get the command line to build, it will still hang when I try to debug. :(

Comment: TomTom, looks like I can build on the command line as you suggested. However. I am still not able to debug my application since VS will hang.  I should also note that VS hangs even if I try to Clean the solution.